# Create datasets containing 15 features with normal distributed PCC

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, python

I am new to the statistics and currently meeting the difficulty of not familiar with the methods of creating correlated datasets.

My task is to assign a normal distributed PCC (Pearson correlation coefficients) to each pair of 15 features (that is, 105 pairs). Then, based on the PCCs, I will generate 10K samples which each with 15 features with each value between 0 and 1.

My idea is using numpy.random.randn to generate a 15*15 correlation symmetric matrix with diagonal being 1. Then use this matrix to run numpy.random.multivariate_normal to generate my datasets.

The difficulties I am meeting is that:

1. How do I constrain each entry of my correlated matrix to be between -1 and 1 so that each entry represents PCC here?
2. How do I constrain each feature value to be between 0 and 1?
3. multivariate_normal takes covariance matrix instead of correlated matrix. Is it necessary to convert my correlation matrix to covariance matrix?

Comment: What is PCC? What is the context?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @user2974951Hi, that is pearson correlation coefficient.

Comment: Could you please explain what a "normal distributed" correlation coefficient is?  It sounds like you wish to generate entries of the variance-covariance matrix according to (independent?) normal distributions, but since no normal distribution has values constrained to the interval $[-1,1],$ this appears to contradict the rest of the question.

Comment: @whuber The original sentence reads, "create a dataset with 10K samples and 15 features, values [0,1], have the features have a PCC out of a normal distribution. Do the investigation for 3 datasets, with that normal distribution of mean (0, 0.5, 0.9) and std 0.2." It might be the case that I misunderstood the question. What do you think about this question?

Comment: I think the question is very confusing because it is grammatically incorrect in many points, is ambiguous, self-contradictory, and inconsistent.  The phrase "PCC out of a normal distribution" is almost nonsensical and has no apparent meaning.

Comment: @whuber I agree. I am asking the question maker for a clearer explanation and maybe come back to update this post. Thank you for your help!